Put information in localStorage with react
I am working on a showcase website for an alcohol brand and I would like when the site is initialized, a component (a modal that I have already created) is displayed for the user's first visit, but not for the following.
My component (legalAge) is a modal that the purpose is to ask if the user is major ^^
my component
where I would like to put it conditionally
I would therefore like to create a variable in the form of a boolean in local storage but I don't really know how to go about it.
I mean I know create the information in local storage, but I don't know how to use it...
I know that this practice is not very reliable in terms of security but I will put up with it for the moment

In your LegalAge Modal, set your localStorage in the onClose function as follows:
const onClose = () => localStorage.setItem("legal_age", JSON.stringify(true));

In your Home component, proceed to get legal_age from localStorage:
const isLegal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("legal_age"));

Then proceed to use the isLegal variable conditionally by using ternary operators or if-else statements

without a useEffect wouldn't the isLegal state remain null initially and the component would always render the LegalAidModal on the first render?

There won't be any need for you to useEffect in this case. LocalStorage data is synchronous, and it will not be null initially. Please feel free to try it out to confirm this.

here is how I do it.
when the component is first rendered look in local storage for your age key. if found set it.
then whenever the age changes the use effect keeps your local storage in sync.
  const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY_AGE = 'age';

  const [age, setAge] = useState(() => {
    const storedAge = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY_AGE);
    return storedAge !== null ? JSON.parse(storedAge) : false;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY_AGE, JSON.stringify(storedAge));
  }, [storedAge]);

